# calling takePicture method of Camera class on SurfaceView. Android, Where to put this one line of code?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

vary simple question about adding only one line of code to this project:

```
   mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback,
        myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
```

I was having some problems with taking a picture using the camera API in Android.  I had it working in another application with no problems, however how can I get it to work in this new app that I show the code below.  the main point is the nested surfaceView class that I want to use for the camera, and the other class that extends View.

notice that in the example there is a surfaceView class that instantiates a Camera object called mCamera.

I tried to call the takePicture method on mCamera.  i was wondering if the reason it does not work is because I am calling the takePicture method from the outer class that the inner surfaceView is nested in without instantiating a surfaceView object?

why does in not work when I call takepicture method for this surfaceView?  is there something missing here, or is the nested surfaceView class set up wrong?

code for the SurfaceView class, this class is nested inside of the main Activity class:

```
    class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
     SurfaceHolder mHolder;
     DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
     boolean mFinished;

     Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
        super(context);

        mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
        mFinished = false;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     }

      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
           mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
           mCamera.startPreview();

           // Preview callback used whenever new viewfinder frame is available
           mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
              public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
              {
                  if ( (mDrawOnTop == null) || mFinished )
                      return;

                  if (mDrawOnTop.mBitmap == null)
                  {
                      // Initialize the draw-on-top companion
                      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight =
                              params.getPreviewSize().height;
                      mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                      mDrawOnTop.mRGBData =
                              new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 
                      mDrawOnTop.mYUVData = new byte[data.length];                    
                  }

                  // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
                  System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                  mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
              }
           });
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mFinished = true;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
        parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    }
```

Next is the vary large class that extends View:

```
  class DrawOnTop extends View {
Bitmap mBitmap;
Paint mPaintBlack;
Paint mPaintYellow;
Paint mPaintRed;
Paint mPaintGreen;
Paint mPaintBlue;
byte[] mYUVData;
int[] mRGBData;
int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
int[] mRedHistogram;
int[] mGreenHistogram;
int[] mBlueHistogram;
double[] mBinSquared;

 public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mPaintBlack = new Paint();
    mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

    mPaintYellow = new Paint();
    mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

    mPaintRed = new Paint();
    mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

    mPaintGreen = new Paint();
    mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

    mPaintBlue = new Paint();
    mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

    mBitmap = null;
    mYUVData = null;
    mRGBData = null;
    mRedHistogram = new int[256];
    mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
    mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
    mBinSquared = new double[256];
    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
    {
        mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
    } // bin
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap != null)
    {
        int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
        int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
        int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

        // Convert from YUV to RGB
        decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Draw bitmap
        mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, /                 mImageWidth, mImageHeight);/            Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
        Rect dst = new Rect(marginWidth, 0, 
                canvasWidth-marginWidth, canvasHeight);/            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaintBlack);

        // Draw black borders                       
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
                canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

        // Calculate histogram
        calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
        calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
        calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

        // Calculate mean
        double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
        double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
            redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
            imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
            greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
            imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
            blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
        } // bin
        imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
        imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
        imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

        // Calculate second moment
        double imageRed2ndMoment = 0, imageGreen2ndMoment = 0, imageBlue2ndMoment = 0;
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
            imageGreen2ndMoment += mGreenHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
            imageBlue2ndMoment += mBlueHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
        } // bin
        imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
        imageGreen2ndMoment /= greenHistogramSum;
        imageBlue2ndMoment /= blueHistogramSum;
        double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageRed2ndMoment - imageRedMean*imageRedMean );
        double imageGreenStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageGreen2ndMoment - imageGreenMean*imageGreenMean );
        double imageBlueStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageBlue2ndMoment - imageBlueMean*imageBlueMean );

        // Draw mean
        String imageMeanStr = "Mean (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenMean)
        + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueMean);
     if(imageRedMean>115){
         if(cameraStatus.get()==false){
         shutterActon();

         }
    }
        canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10, 30, mPaintYellow);

        // Draw standard deviation
        String imageStdDevStr = "Std Dev (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenStdDev)
        + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueStdDev);
        canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
        canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10, 60, mPaintYellow);

        // Draw red intensity histogram
        float barMaxHeight = 3000;
        float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
        float barMarginHeight = 2;
        RectF barRect = new RectF();
        barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 200;
        barRect.left = marginWidth;
        barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
            barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
            Math.min(80,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
        //  canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
            barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
            //canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintRed);
            barRect.left += barWidth;
            barRect.right += barWidth;
        } // bin

        // Draw green intensity histogram
        barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 100;
        barRect.left = marginWidth;
        barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum)
            * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
        //  canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
            barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
            //canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGreen);
            barRect.left += barWidth;
            barRect.right += barWidth;
        } // bin

        // Draw blue intensity histogram
        barRect.bottom = canvasHeight;
        barRect.left = marginWidth;
        barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum)
            * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
        //  canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
            barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
            //canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlue);
            barRect.left += barWidth;
            barRect.right += barWidth;
        } // bin
    } // end if statement

    super.onDraw(canvas);

} // end onDraw method

public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
            if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
            if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
}

public void decodeYUV420SPGrayscale(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
{
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++)
    {
        int pixVal = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[pix])) - 16;
        if (pixVal < 0) pixVal = 0;
        if (pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;
        rgb[pix] = 0xff000000 | (pixVal << 16) | (pixVal << 8) | pixVal;
    } // pix
}

public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
{
    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
    {
        histogram[bin] = 0;
    } // bin
    if (component == 0) // red
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
        {
            int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
            histogram[ pixVal ]++;
        } // pix
    }
    else if (component == 1) // green
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
        {
            int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
            histogram[ pixVal ]++;
        } // pix
    }
    else // blue
    {
        for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
        {
            int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
            histogram[ pixVal ]++;
        } // pix
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback,myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);` where ever you want to trigger the taking of a picture, eg. after a button click or screen press etc